# Delphi - Open a PDF with Internet Explorer fails

Tags: delphi, internet-explorer, debugging, pdf

We open within of our program an online-pdf file:

`ShellExecute(Handle, nil, PChar( URL ), nil,  nil, SW_SHOWNORMAL);`

This should open the pdf with the standard browser. This works fine with FireFox. But with the Internet Explorer as default we have the following problem:

The IE will open the pdf if the IE wasn't started yet. If the IE is already running then nothing is happening.

BUT - it works if we start the program within the debugger!

Any idea what could be the reason and how to avoid it?

(I know that as a workaround I could try to download the pdf first and open it from a local folder - but I didn't try that yet).

Comment: Different browsers behave different. As a workaround to make it browser-independent, your program could download the PDF document resource from the web server and then open it locally with the default PDF viewer.

Comment: But when I run the URL directly in the start commandline (not sure how to call it exactly in English) then it also works. So I assume that it has something to do how i call it within of Delphi.

Comment: Does the program work correctly if you start it from the Delphi IDE with the "Run without debugging" menu command?

Comment: It didn't work correctly with "Run without debugging". It seems so whether it was a timing issue. More information at my answer

Answer (score 0):

I found now by accident the reason for the problem.
We open 2 URLs (I didn't write it in the question since I thought it doesn't matter). One is opening a website for more information - the other one is opening a PDF.
If the Internet Explorer is running it gets the 1st message to open an URL. While the IE is busy it seems to ignore all other incoming messages. So the call to open the PDF will be ignored.

This is certainly also the reason why it worked in the debugger. The program was some ms slower.

So I wait now 0.5 s before opening the second URL. And everything seems fine again.